# Merging multiple homebrew links

Tags: macos, homebrew

I need to install a bunch of python3 versions `(3.7 3.8 3.9)` at the same time.  I would like to have ALL of these linked, with the latest (or whichever I choose) taking the `python3` and `pip3` links

However if I use `--overwrite` it does `unlink 3.7 && link 3.8` instead.

Other than manually merging the links, is there any way to tell it to `--overwrite --merge` aka keep any non-conflicting links?

Comment: Isn’t this just what https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv is for? Install with brew and away you go.

Comment: yes you can also use pyenv, I was wondering if there is a way to just use brew's inbuilt versioning instead

Comment: Brew is not a version manager.

Comment: I get that.  Yet we still have multiple python@ version right now, so it could be temporarily used as such.
Let's say I wanted to install the `coreutils` package. If it had partial conflicts with another package, perhaps I install `realpath` in another package… would there be no way to merge?